# Add new column in df1, if value of df1 comes in range of df2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Compare two dataframes. If value of df1 is overlapping with the value of df2 column value, if should add one new column with value 'Yes' or 'No'.

Condition:

```py
if df1['chr'] == df2['chr']
   df1['Status'] = df1['position'].between(df2['start'],df2['end']
```

```
df1<tab separated>
name    chr position
res1    c1  98
res2    c4  143
res3    c1  108

df2<tab separated>
chr start   end
c1  78  97
c2  108 143
c1  143 108
```

Output:

```
res1    c1  98  no
res2    c4  143 no
res3    c1  108 yes
```

```py
def overlap_region(H3K27ac_file,snp_list):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(H3K27ac_file, sep="\t",header=None,header=0)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(snp_list, sep="\t",header=0)

    df1['position'].between(df2['start'],df2['end']

    print(df1)
x = overlap_region(x,y)
```